# Integrate Twitter in a website

Tags: c#, twitter, oauth

I am trying to get a website to connect to a Twitter account so that I can display the tweets on my website.  I can get the application to work when you connect via the OAuth authentication and it asks if I want to allow the application.

What I want to do, is because it's my own Twitter account, I want to be able to login without having to do this every time.  I want the website to send my credentials across so that the user just sees the page, and can view the tweets.  Is this possible?

Comment: Do you need to login? Aren't your tweets public? I realise you get better request rate by logging in but you ought to cache them on the server side anyway and refresh infrequently anyway.

Comment: @Rup: I need to login in order to show tweets that are protected.

Comment: ok that invalidates my response :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured this out.  I created a new class that inherits the IConsumerTokenManager interface.  Then, the only properties I needed to change were `ConsumerKey`, `ConsumerSecret` and `GetTokenSecret` (as shown below).

```
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.ChannelElements;
using DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Messages; 
#endregion

namespace BingMapTest
{
    public class ConsumerTokenManager : IConsumerTokenManager
    {
        public string ConsumerKey
        {
            get { return "xxxxxxxx"; }
        }

        public string ConsumerSecret
        {
            get { return "xxxxxxxx"; }
        }

        public string GetTokenSecret(string token)
        {
            return "xxxxxxxx";
        }

        public void ExpireRequestTokenAndStoreNewAccessToken(string consumerKey, string requestToken, string accessToken, string accessTokenSecret)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public TokenType GetTokenType(string token)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public bool IsRequestTokenAuthorized(string requestToken)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void StoreNewRequestToken(UnauthorizedTokenRequest request, ITokenSecretContainingMessage response)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, back in my Page_Load method I instantiate the new `ConsumerTokenManager`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ITwitterAuthorization auth;

            ConsumerTokenManager tokenManager = new ConsumerTokenManager();

            auth = new WebOAuthAuthorization(tokenManager, "accessToken");
            auth.UseCompression = true;

            // For Twitter
            using (var twitterCtx = new TwitterContext(auth, "https://api.twitter.com/1/", "https://search.twitter.com/"))
            {                   
                // Whatever authorization module we selected... sign on now.  
                try
                {
                    auth.SignOn();
                }
                catch (OperationCanceledException)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

Thought I'd share incase anyone else has a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

If your account is not protected, you can use the public timeline like:

```
http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/mytwittername.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=4
```

this will give you the last 4 tweets, there are other ways to retrieve your tweets whithout authentication

Answer (score 0):

You still have to use oauth.

The idea is that when you logged in, any oauth API returns an access token. Sometimes the access token needs to be re-requested periodically, but in Twitter's case [the FAQ states](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_faq) (almost at the bottom) that they don't expire them.

This access token is used to sign all future calls - such as retrieving tweets, etc..